# logout a specific user with cakephp Auth Component

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I want to logout a specific user using the logout method (cakephp Auth Component)

`$this->Auth->logout();`

but it always logout the current logged user !!

thanks

Comment: is there any way to get the session id of a specific connected user ?

Comment: With addons like [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/tag/who-is-online/) probably. At least this way I am able to force-logout specific users.